# Spring WebFlux rest controller serves only first two subscriptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, eventsource

There's a flux created programmatically by `Flux.create` method:

```
Flux<Tweet> flux = Flux.<Tweet>create(emitter -> ...);
```

There's a rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class StreamController {
    ...

    @GetMapping("/top-words")
    public Flux<TopWords> streamTopWords() {
        return topWordsStream.getTopWords();
    }
}
```

There's a couple of web clients (in standalone processes):

```
Flux<TopWords> topWordsFlux = WebClient.create(".../top-words")
        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(TopWords.class)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

There's a couple of EventSource instances in JavaScript:

```
var eventSource = new EventSource(".../top-words");

eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log("Processing message: ", e.data);
};
```

Only the first two "subscribers" will start receiving the messages (no matter if it's a web client or EventSource instance). The other will open the connection, get HTTP 200 status, but the event stream stays empty. There're no errors on either client or server side.

I don't understand, where is the limit on "2 subscribers" imposed. What do I have to do, if I want to support more than 2 subscribers?

The application is built with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and auto-configured with spring-boot-starter-webflux. The default configuration is not changed.

Comment: could you provide more information about the implementation providing `Flux<TopWords>` (code snippet)? What are you seeing if you're adding a `.log()` operator here: `.getTopWords().log()`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It was a limitation of the underlying API that I tried to adapt (Twitter streaming API). I created the Flux through ``Flux.create`` and didn't realize the emitter is used per-subscriber (not shared). It was clearly my misunderstanding, as the documentation is clear in this regard.

Comment: Interesting! Feel free to answer your own question, this might be interesting to others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation in the underlying API that I tried to adapt (Twitter streaming API).

The goal was to connect to Twitter once and process tweet stream by various different subscribers.

Originally I thought the emitter passed to `Flux.create` method always uses the same `FluxSink` for all subscribers. That of course doesn't make sense. Instead the `FluxSink` is provided per-subscriber, as the javadoc states clearly.

I implemented my use case with a Twitter listener that allows for registration (and un-registration) of a number of `FluxSink` instances. That way, the single tweet stream can be subscribed to by various different subsribers.

```
Flux<Tweet> flux = Flux.<Tweet>create(twitterListener::addSink);
```

My `twitterListener` implements `org.springframework.social.twitter.api.StreamListener` from spring-social-twitter project.